# Give condition for choosing one mode when there are more than one in R

Tags: r, mode

I have a categoric variable for which I want to find the mode. In particular, I want to find the mode for the variable Ethic group, i.e. the most common ethnic group. I will do that grouping by household, i.e. finding the most common ethnic group in a household. The problem is, if there are more than one mode (more than one ethnic group are dominant one), then I would like to get the one from the household head (there is another variable that indicates whether the person is the household head).

Basically, we would have the table HQ2:

```
H_Code      Rela_HH Ethn
1    AS-01      10  SEN
2    AS-01       1  SEN
3    AS-02       1   FA
4    AS-02       2   MA
5    AS-02       4   MA
6    AS-02       4   FA
7    AS-03       1   NZ
8    AS-03       2   MA
```

Where H_Code=Household code, Rela_HH=relation to household head (1 means household head), Ethn=ethnic group.

You will see that AS-02 has two modes: FA and MA. In this case, I want R to give me the one of the person with value=1 for Rela_HH.

So far, I have just managed to do a normal mode and can't find a way to code for the additional bit.

> ```
> Mode <- function(x) {
>   ux <- unique(x)
>   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(, ux)))]
> }
>
>
> HQ2$c <-  with(HQ2, ave(Ethn, H_Code, FUN=Mode))
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a good `data.table` method to do this. I'll edit my answer if I come up with one. Right now I have an easy way to do this with `order` and `dplyr`. Note that the `Mode` function will take the first `Ethn`, so I reordered them in hq2 to demonstrate.

#### Dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
hq2 <- data.table(H_Code = c("AS-01", "AS-01", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-03", "AS-03"), Rela_HH = c(10,1,1,2,4,4,2,1), Ethn = c("SEN", "SEN", "FA", "MA", "MA", "FA", "NZ", "MA"))

hq2[order(H_Code, Rela_HH), ] %>% 
  group_by(H_Code) %>% 
  summarize(Ethn_Mode = Mode(Ethn))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  H_Code Ethn_Mode
  <chr>  <chr>    
1 AS-01  SEN      
2 AS-02  MA       
3 AS-03  MA
```

#### Data Table

If you had a big table, you could set your keys to `H_Code` and `Rela_HH` to make some quicker sorting.

```
library(data.table)

hq1 <- as.data.table(hq2)
hq1[order(H_Code, Rela_HH), ][, Mode(Ethn), by = list(H_Code)]

   H_Code  V1
1:  AS-01 SEN
2:  AS-02  MA
3:  AS-03  MA
```

*Edits*

Here is the revised `dplyr` code.

```
hq3 %>% 
  group_by(H_Code, Ethn) %>% 
  mutate(eth_count = sum(n())) %>% 
  mutate(priority = all(1 %in% Rela_HH & !1 %in% eth_count)) %>% 
  arrange(H_Code, desc(priority), desc(eth_count), Rela_HH) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(H_Code) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% 1)
```

Here is the revised `data.table` code, which does not use any `mode` function. What it does is create a `priority` column, which is set to `TRUE` if any ethnicity occurs more than once, and an entry in that group has a `1` set in `Rela_HH`. You then set your sorting order to work out the order and any ties (`H_Code, -priority, -count, Rela_HH`).

Three datasets that have different scenarios, `hq3` (HH ethnicity occurs >1, but < non-HH), `hq4` (HH ethnicity occurs 1), and `hq5` (HH ethnicity occurs >1, and > non-HH).

```
hq3 <- data.table(H_Code = c("AS-01", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-03", "AS-03"), Rela_HH = c(10,4,3,2,1,5,2,1), Ethn = c("SEN", "FA", "FA", "FA", "MA", "MA", "NZ", "MA"))
hq4 <- data.table(H_Code = c("AS-01", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-03", "AS-03"), Rela_HH = c(10,4,3,2,1,5,2,1), Ethn = c("SEN", "MA", "FA", "FA", "ZA", "MA", "NZ", "MA"))
hq5 <- data.table(H_Code = c("AS-01", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-02", "AS-03", "AS-03"), Rela_HH = c(10,4,3,2,1,5,2,1), Ethn = c("SEN", "MA", "FA", "FA", "MA", "MA", "NZ", "MA"))

hq3[, `:=` (count = .N), by = list(H_Code, Ethn)][, priority := all(1 %in% Rela_HH & !1 %in% count), by = list(H_Code, Ethn)][order(H_Code, Rela_HH, -count), ] # leave off the last [] section, it's here to show this output in order

   H_Code Rela_HH Ethn count priority
1:  AS-01      10  SEN     1    FALSE
2:  AS-02       1   MA     2     TRUE
3:  AS-02       2   FA     3    FALSE
4:  AS-02       3   FA     3    FALSE
5:  AS-02       4   FA     3    FALSE
6:  AS-02       5   MA     2     TRUE
7:  AS-03       1   MA     1    FALSE
8:  AS-03       2   NZ     1    FALSE

hq3[order(H_Code, -priority, -count, Rela_HH), ][hq3[, .I[1], by = list(H_Code)]$V1]

   H_Code Rela_HH Ethn count priority
1:  AS-01      10  SEN     1    FALSE
2:  AS-02       1   MA     2     TRUE
3:  AS-03       1   MA     1    FALSE
```

#### Benchmark

Which one is faster? Data.table, roughly by a factor of 2, and with keys set on a big table, maybe more.

```
> microbenchmark(DTmeth(hq1), dplyrmeth(hq2), neval = 1000)
Unit: nanoseconds
           expr     min      lq       mean    median      uq     max neval cld
    DTmeth(hq1)  624865  641316  665616.17  654145.5  677087  847038   100  b 
 dplyrmeth(hq2) 1144980 1161583 1202274.35 1180147.5 1223617 1651814   100   c
          neval       0       0       3.56       1.0       1     303   100 a
```

Revised code test (I'm curious if there's a better way for `data.table` to do this since it's about equal with `dplyr` now):

```
Unit: nanoseconds
            expr     min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
     DTmeth(hq5)  653542  683727.5  773249.70  706670.5  747120.5  1791880   100  b 
    DT2meth(hq5) 1670831 1816633.0 1947881.22 1874742.5 2040164.5  2892786   100   c
  dplyrmeth(hq3) 1169733 1232672.5 1587836.22 1281876.5 1367757.5 24089844   100   c
 dplyr2meth(hq3) 1414848 1506917.5 1903192.98 1541481.5 1631438.0 26743551   100   c
           neval       0       1.0      18.88       1.0       1.0      303   100 a
```

Comment: I have been working with the data.table option, as I do not totally understand the other one. The problem is that it still sorts it by alphabetic order in hq1. So I obtain a table with two columns (household code and mode ethnic group). When there are more than one mode, I get them sorted in alphabetic order. If I could add a column to hq1 where it says the rela_HH, then I would know how to continue (subsetting for rela_HH=1).

Comment: If I do this:
hq1 <- as.data.table(HQ2)
hq1<-hq1[order(H_Code, Rela_HH), ][1:214, .(Mode(Ethn), Rela_HH), by = list(H_Code)]
Still, it is sorting Rela_HH independently than Mode(EThn) so the values of the two columns do not correspond. 
I think what needs to be changed is the formula of the mode, but not sure how to...

Comment: Adjusting the dataset, it looks like if the mode is equal (2 vs 2), the tie is broken by `Rela_HH`. If the mode is greater for the non-head ethnicity, it goes with the larger mode, so you are right, it needs to be adjusted.

Comment: I think I've come up with a solution. Test it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: You're welcome, also upvote if the answer was useful.